# How do I get the number of continuos block in the sea of 0s

Tags: c++

I have been struggling for weeks to solve this problem, if any experienced programer could help I would be happy.

Lets say that we have matrix like this:

```
111000000000
111000000000
111000011111
111110010111
001111010110
000000010110
011101001100
011100000000
011100000000
000111100110
000011100110
110011100000
```

And I have to return the number of continous blocks of 1s. Basicaly, 0s are water and 1s land and the question is how many continents there are in the sea. Answer is 6. 
I tried to check the values in 2D matrix, but I can not do well the condition statements to recognise the continous block.

Comment: did you write any code? Please include it in the question.

Comment: Have you tried BFS Algorithm?

Comment: You may have an easier time if you convert the binary to text format, and use `std::string`.

Comment: Do diagonally touching regions count as connected?

Comment: Yes it counts diagonally as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm to mark all the touching ones. If you can mark all the touching ones, you can just iterate over the entire matrix and try to start at each one that was not visited yet.

```
int main() {
    // n and m are the dimensions of your original matrix
    int matrix[n+2][m+2]; //extra rows and columns on the edges to prevent going outside of memory

    for(int i = 0; i <= n + 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= m + 1; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            //get the data somehow...
        }
    }

    int continent = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            queue<pair<int, int>> bfs; //a queue for the algorithm

            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                 bfs.push({ i, j }); //push starting point to the array

                 continent++;
                 matrix[i][j] = continent + 1;

                 while (!bfs.empty()) {
                     pair<int, int> curr = bfs.top(); //take the current location from the queue
                     bfs.pop();

                     //check if there are any ones int the cardinal direcitions
                     //if there are, replace the one with the current number and add its location to the queue
                     if (matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first + 1, curr.second });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first][curr.second + 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first][curr.second + 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first, curr.second + 1 });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first - 1, curr.second });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first][curr.second - 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first][curr.second - 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first, curr.second - 1 });
                     }

                     //and check diagonals
                     if (matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second + 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second + 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first + 1, curr.second + 1 });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second + 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second + 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first - 1, curr.second + 1 });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second - 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first + 1][curr.second - 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first + 1, curr.second - 1 });
                     }
                     if (matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second - 1] == 1) {
                         matrix[curr.first - 1][curr.second - 1] = continent + 1;
                         bfs.push({ curr.first - 1, curr.second - 1 });
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << continent;
}
```